# React typed(script) props are not checked

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am starting a fresh new app with React, and I give a try to TypeScript for the first time. I got a React component such as:

```
import React, { SFC } from 'react';

type Props = {
    username: string
};

export const Navbar: SFC<Props> = ({ username }: Props) => (
    <div>Hello {username}!</div>
);
```

It compiles correctly. However, Visual Code doesn't warn me about an invalid use of my component:

```
{/* no required username */}
<Navbar />

{/* number instead of string */}
<Navbar username={12} />
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json` configuration:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"],
  "types": ["typePatches"]
}
```

I would expect my IDE and the compiler to warn me about this misuse. But this is not the case. What am I missing? Is it the expected behavior? Or just a misconfiguration?

Comment: It should work, how are you importing the NavBar?

Comment: With an `import Navbar from './Navbar`. So that's perhaps an IDE issue?

Comment: Your incorrect usages of `<Navbar />` that the compiler fails to complain about - are these in a .jsx file or a .tsx file?

Comment: Indeed, that was a `.js` file. My bad! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your code lives in files with a `.tsx` extension, you should just get the behavior you expect.

If you're using `<Navbar />` in a `.jsx` file, you can get the compiler to complain by adding `"checkJS": true` in your tsconfig.

---

Oddly enough, I don't see any mention of `checkJS` in the [tsconfig docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html), although it is documented in the [compiler options docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

This omission from the tsconfig documentation initially led me to believe that only the `allowJS` flag is needed to get the compiler to complain about mistakes in js or jsx files.

The compiler options documentation *does* correctly call out that the `checkJS` flag needs to be used *in conjunction with* the `allowJS` flag.